# Extracting buildings contours

Tags: python-3.x, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, detection, contour

i'm trying to get buildings contours from zenith aerial images (like on the attached picture). I want to automatically get training data to convolution neural network. I have tried many things but without effects. Maybe you have some ideas.

[image: The exaple of a zenith aerial picture]

Comment: What about canny edge detection?

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

Comment: I have combined with Canny edge detection parameters and without sensible effects.
(https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LcpmutulsvID-L2-GjgfOl7Rrs7KgZHT)https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LcpmutulsvID-L2-GjgfOl7Rrs7KgZHT